# Can a void-returning function g return f(); when f returns void?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11

Consider the following snippet:

```
void f(void);

void g(…)
{
  …
  return f();
  …
}
```

Is this `return f();` valid according to C11?

I am not advocating using this pattern: if it works at all, it is obviously equivalent to `f(); return;` (where the `return;` itself would be redundant if this is at the end of function `g()`). I am asking this question in the context of the static analysis of C programs, where the C code has already been written by someone else and the question is deciding whether or not it is valid according to the standard.

I would interpret C11 6.8.6.4:1 as meaning that it is non-standard and should be statically rejected. Is it possible to interpret it differently (I have found this pattern in actual and otherwise high-quality source code)?

> **Constraints**
>
> A return statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is void. A return statement without an expression shall only appear in a function whose return type is void.

Comment: Does the compiler you are using reject the code, accept the code quietly or accept it with a warning? Was the code once ISO C?

Comment: @RayToal GCC accepts the program in al-Khwārizmī's answer with `-std=c11 -Wall` without a peep, but `-pedantic` causes a diagnostic.

Comment: Clang warns with `-Wpedantic` as well: `void function 'f' should not return void expression [-Wpedantic]`

Comment: GCC diagnosing only with `-pedantic` is a good indicator that this is a conforming extension. I assume this is for compatibility with C++, where [stmt.return]/3 says "A return statement with an expression of type void can be used only in functions with a return type of cv void; the expression is evaluated just before the function returns to its caller."

Comment: The sentence "A return statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is void" also appears in the [C89 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html), so the fact that compilers warn rather than generate static errors here is probably just a pragmatic choice.

Comment: @casey, consider writing an answer. It seems very likely that this is a construct taken over from C++.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Anything after `return` is an expression.

#### 6.8.6:1 Jump statements

```
Syntax  

   ...
   return expressionopt;
```

And standard says that:

> A return statement **with an expression** shall not appear in a function whose return type
>   is void. ....

`f()` is also an expression here. The compiler should raise a warning

```
[Warning] ISO C forbids 'return' with expression, in function returning void [-pedantic]
```

Comment: You are right: I didn't look at it this way, but the grammar in 6.8.6:1 makes it clear that `f()` should be considered as an expression: it cannot be anything else according to the grammar.

Answer (score 10):

This clearly is a constraint violation, in particular in view of

> 6.3.2.2 void: The (nonexistent) value of a void expression (an expression that has type void) shall not be used in any way,

That means that the incomplete type `void` is a dead end that cannot be reused for any purpose whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly states `A return statement without an expression shall only appear in a function whose return type is void`, try and execute this:

```
void g()
{
    return; // does not return any expression at all
}
void f()
{
    return g();
}


int main(void) {
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It compiles for me with a warning; *Extraneous return value*.

Comment: For me the the code is valid, there should be no warnings.

Comment: @al-Khwārizmī Even if you compile with `-Wall`?