# Void Function Returns Int and Void

Tags: c++, c

I tried to write a void function with a return type and for some reason that works fine.
Here is the some code I tried to compile:

```
void a(){
  return b();
}
void b()
{
   printf("%s","void:)");
}
```

And the next code also works correctly:

```
 int main()
 {
  a();
  return 0;
 }

 void a(){
  return 5;
 }
```

Which of the above is correct according to the standard?

Second, why does it compile?

Comment: Make sure you compile with maximum number of warnings and strictness.

Comment: I doubt the second one works.

Comment: just because you can squeeze it through the compiler doesn't mean it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

> Which of the above is correct according to the standard?

Neither is correct according to C and C++ standard. C standard says that:

#### 6.8.6.4 The return statement:

> A `return` statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type
>   is `void`. A `return` statement without an expression shall only appear in a function
>   whose return type is `void`.

Also read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22509182/2455888) for more detailed explanation.

> Second, why does it compile?

Compilation doesn't guarantee that your code can't produce errors. It can. Better to compile your code with maximum warning flags.  I compiled the second code with following options and got the following warnings:

```
In function 'main':
    [Warning] implicit declaration of function 'a' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
At top level:
    [Warning] conflicting types for 'a' [enabled by default]
    [Note] previous implicit declaration of 'a' was here
In function 'a':
    [Warning] 'return' with a value, in function returning void [enabled by default]
```

Although code compiled but there are some errors and violation of C standard.

Answer (score 1):

Both programs are **invalid**. You failed to provide a function definition or declaration of `b()` in the first program before calling it in `a()`, and you failed to provide a function definition of `a()` before calling it in `main()` in the second program.

Your compiler is providing a "default" prototype for an undeclared function:

```
int func();
```

which is a function taking **any arguments** and returning `int`. This is probably not what you want. Your compiler should have issued a warning saying that it was supplying a default function declaration.

If you forward-declare the functions correctly (`void b();` and `void a();`), the compiler will correctly reject both programs.